# Importing roottools.jar into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, roottools

I'm trying to import roottools from here: https://code.google.com/p/roottools/ (jar file) to the Android Studio project. So far I've tried the following:

- copy RootTools-javadoc-3.4.jar into libs directory under my project.
- Add imports
- Reorganize imports.
- Rebuild project

But still I don't have "acces" to it's methods. Is it possible that is only compatible with Eclipse?

Comment: Are you using gradle?

Comment: Android Studio 0.4.3 or 0.4.4? You've added the library from Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies?

Comment: include your project structure and module's build.gradle file.

Comment: @Scott Barta It's 0.4.4. The lib is added in Other Settings --> Default project Structure --> Libraries. I cannot find any "modules" there.

Comment: Can someone explain how to add RootTools as a gradle dependency, through github repo url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried using the JAR available for download and it didn't work either. To get this working, I had to download the project available at github [here](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools). Compile and run the task "makeJar" (right click on **task makeJar** in the gradle.build and select run).

I just added this new jar in the libs and referenced in the gradle.build file.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile files('libs/RootTools.jar')
}
```

or you can add it via Project Properties.

It worked perfectly (don't forget to sync your the gradle files if you edit it manually).

Comment: I can't find makeJar task in the Android Studio.

Comment: @soulreaver It's in the gradle.build file of the RootTools project

Comment: Wow thanks, It works perfectly... And besides I didn't know I can run tasks from the build file that way. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

In your project, choose **File** menu > **Project Structure** (there's a bug in 0.4.4 and this menu item won't have a title at all; it still works) > **Modules** > choose your module > **Dependencies** > + button > **File dependency** > choose your library from the file picker. That file needs to be somewhere beneath the root directory of your projet; the **libs** directory is fine.

Screenshot of the Project Structure dialog:

[image: Project Structure showing Modules > Dependencies > File Dependency]